# How to return a slice in Java

Tags: java, slice, javacard

I am working on a JavaCard, so a SIM card that runs Java (or a subset of it: Java Embedded). Due to memory limitations I have an array that I reuse for multiple tasks.

I want a function to basically return a pointer to that array, with an offset, thus a slice. This way I can be sure that no part of that array will be overwritten by accident.

Pointers dont exactly exist in Java, but is there a way to return a part of an array without copying it?

Comment: What features do you need from the array? You could easily make a "Slice" class with a get/put that handles the offset for you. You just can't use `[]` for accessing the elements.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. Object (references) is the closest you can get to pointers in Java.

If this were regular Java, I would have suggested, to wrap the array in a `List` with `Arrays.asList` and then use the `List` method `subList`, which provides a view of a section of the list without copying its contents.

However If I read the JavaCard API reference correctly these aren't included. You could try write a simple version of those interfaces/classes/methods yourself.

Comment: I would definitely not recommend making anything that slices arrays in Javacard or anything that mimics asList or subList. These are not included for a reason as garbage collection is almost non-existent on JavacardOS due to hardware limitations and slicing would cause garbage and memory leaks.

Comment: @Asthor Dumb question: What is the point of classes in JavaCard or even JavaCard in general if you can't release the memory used?

Comment: Not sure there are dumb questions with Javacard, @RoToRa, as it is a bit of a special way to code. Comments are too short for a good answer so will generalize a bit, but all the object orientation done in Javacard needs to be done as if everything is a singleton. This means everything gets allocated on startup, through constructors and then re-used, Including arrays. The only exception is primitives that can be allocated and used. This might sound awful but the drawbacks are worth it for the security benefits javacard offers on small devices. like the chip in your bank card or SIM card.